# 'contentsOf ' is not showing up when I use Data

Tags: swift, scope

if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataFilePath!)

like I made last time, I tried to make this one again and this "contentsOf" dose not showing up when I type Data and if I type manually, an error pops up saying cannot find contentsOf: in scope

is there specific condition that I can use contentsOf: ?

```
import UIKit

class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray: [Data] = []
    
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("item.plist")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodoListCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].title
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Todo List", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { (myTextField) in
            myTextField.placeholder = "What's your new plan?"
            textField = myTextField
        }
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (alertAction) in
            let newItem = Data()
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            
            self.itemArray.append(newItem)
            
            self.saveData()
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func saveData() {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(itemArray)
            try data.write(to: path)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let data = **Data(contentsOf:)**
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You didn't write `dataFilePath`?

Comment: You never call loadData (you could call it in viewDidLoad) and you do not create file in case it does not exist. Also you do not save data when removing item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that

```
let newItem = Data()
newItem.title = textField.text!
```

doesn't seem to throw an Error here makes me believe that you created your own class/struct with the name `Data`

in this case Data(contentsOf: ...) might not be defined and found

Two options if I'm right:

- try Foundation.Data(contentsOf: ...)
- rename your declaration of Data

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data

IMHO you should rename you Data class since it’s already declared in Apple Foundation